# Fetch of Entity mapped by JoinColumns with LazyNoProxy annotation not working with criteriaquery - leading to n + queries

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, criteria, criteria-api

We have one entity Film that has various mapped entities Producer, MainActor all lazily loaded, and an entity BiggestStar lazily loaded and joined via @JoinColumns annotation over 2 different columns FirstName and LastName with no foreign key.

```
public class Film implements PersistentAttributeInterceptable {
   private PersistentAttributeInterceptor interceptor;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "film")
   @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
   @LazyGroup("producer")
   public Producer getProducer() {
       return producer;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
   @JoinColumns(foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT),
    value = {@JoinColumn(name = "starFirstName", referencedColumnName = "firstName", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "starLastName", referencedColumnName = "lastName", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
   @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
   @LazyGroup("biggestStar")
   public BiggestStar biggestStar() {
       if (interceptor != null) {
           return (F) interceptor.readObject(this, "biggestStar", biggestStar);
       }
       return biggestStar;
   } 
}
```

I have one criteriaquery where I want to get entity Film and fetch Producer, BiggestStar but not the MainActor.

```
CriteriaQuery<Film> query = cb.createQuery(Film.class);
Root<Film> root= query.from(Film.class);
root.fetch(Film_.producer, JoinType.LEFT);
root.fetch(Film_.biggestStar, JoinType.LEFT);
query.select(root).where(...)
```

now if i execute this query I get exactly one SQL statement logged that accurately fetches all of my objectes and I get all the values for the tables Film, Producer and BiggestStar
but when the getter on `film.getBiggestStar()` is called there is another statement issued selecting the join columns on the film table.
When inspecting the film object the biggestStar is null until you do a getBiggestStar() but then does not issue another command to the biggestStar table but only to the film table.

like

```
select starFirstName, starLastName from Film
```

resulting in n+1 queries as I use this query for fetching the data for a table.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here how I could achieve a fast fetch of all those entities in one query by keeping the lazy loading.

some disclaimers:

- I know I could use native SQL
- I do not have power over the database so I can not add foreign keys or improve the data schema
- the database is Oracle 12